# How to stop draggable from reverting to original position

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating my own custom material design slider in Angular 4 and i have come to a point where if i drag the slider thumb it moves but on mouseup it reverts back to original position.

I read up on the dragEvents but since the droppable area is the very same object that i drag, i cannot seem to find a solution to make it stop reverting back to original position.

You can use this url to replicate this behavior as it is enough code to make the page long

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ndu2t**

Answer (score 0):

Adding a dragend handler will fix it:

```
    this.slider.addEventListener('dragend', this.onDrag.bind(this), false);
```

When you add a log to your event listener you see the x (and y) are negative when you let go of the mouse but since dragend will give the correct values as the last one it fixes the problem:

```
onDrag(event: DragEvent) {
  console.log(event.x);
  this.updateValueFromPosition({ x: event.x, y: event.y });
}
```